# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail" (from Rest Framework Quickstart)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am following the tutorial for rest framework. I have no idea this part of the code ain't working when it works for the apigroups. Please tell me what is the underlying issue. Thank you.

ERROR:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /polls/users/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Serializers:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['url', 'name']
```

#Views

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

#Urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

# for rest framework
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `basename` to your router register:

```
router.register(r'snippets', SnippetViewSet, basename='snippet')
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
```

Comment: still not working. I tried using basename='user' and basename='users' ...

Comment: @SuraAmilbahar It didn't work for me either